# Ember StateManager, injecting controllers and using initialState

Tags: ember.js

I have the following StateManager which deals with a couple of views.  I would like to not have to manually transition into the initial state with  `App.stateManager.transitionTo('showingPhotos')`.  I would prefer just to use the `initialState` property of the state manager.

Using the `initialState` property of the of the StateManager doesn't work in this case though because the controllers are not available until they are injected in with `App.initialize(App.stateManager)`.

Is there a way to avoid having to manually transition into the initial state whilst also injecting the controllers?  Is there a better way to structure a state manager like this?

I have created two JSfiddles:

http://jsfiddle.net/GmD8A/ - this works but I have to manually transition into the initial state

http://jsfiddle.net/tgbuX/ - this uses `initialState` rather than manually transitioning into the initial state and hence doesn't work.

```js
PhotosListView = Ember.View.extend({
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<h2>Showing Photos</h2><a {{action "showContacts"}}>Show Contacts</a>')
});

ContactsListView = Ember.View.extend({
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<h2>Showing Contacts</h2><a {{action "showPhotos"}}>Show Photos</a>')
});

StateManager = Ember.StateManager.extend({
  rootElement: '#body',
  showingContacts: Ember.ViewState.extend({
    view: ContactsListView,
    showPhotos: function(manager) {
      manager.transitionTo('showingPhotos');
    },
    enter: function(manager) {
      this._super(manager);
      this.setPath('view.controller', manager.get('photosController'));
    }
  }),
  showingPhotos: Ember.ViewState.extend({
    view: PhotosListView,
    showContacts: function(manager) {
      manager.transitionTo('showingContacts');
    },
    enter: function(manager) {
      this._super(manager);
      this.setPath('view.controller', manager.get('contactsController'));
    }
  })
});

App                    = Ember.Application.create()
App.PhotosController   = Ember.ArrayController.extend()
App.ContactsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend()
App.stateManager       = StateManager.create()

App.initialize(App.stateManager) // This injects the controllers
App.stateManager.transitionTo('showingPhotos') // I don't want to have to manually transition into this initial state
```

​

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look to the latest Ember version, which now has a Router, autowired with any `*Controller` classes instance, and managing `outlets` the way you intend to.

You could start with https://gist.github.com/2679013 & https://gist.github.com/2728699

**EDIT**

You have a new in-progress guide @ https://emberjs-staging-new.herokuapp.com/guides/outlets#toc_the-router